# Get user gender from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to get a user's gender using the facebook sdk for Android. I am using parse to login/signup so I have access to all users id and access token. When I try and make a new HTTP GET request, I can only get MY information - but I need [user_x]'s information. If I use the Graph API Explorer it works just fine, but in code it doesn't work. Here's some of the code I have:

Login:

```
 List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email","basic_info", "user_about_me", "user_location", "public_profile");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uh Oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User's like new or something.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        user.put("facebookId", currentUser.getJSONObject("authData").getJSONObject("facebook").get("id").toString());
                        user.put("access_token", currentUser.getJSONObject("authData").getJSONObject("facebook").get("access_token").toString());
                        user.save();
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        Log.e("Nope", ex.toString());
                    }

                    login();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User just like logged in or something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    login();
                }
            }
        });
```

Request:

```
/* make the API call */
                new Request(
                        ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
                        "/1376286562687763",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new Request.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                Log.d(response.toString(), "");
                                try {
                                    Log.d(response.getGraphObject().getProperty("gender").toString(), "");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("oops", e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
```

If I type that ID in the Graph API Explorer - works like a charm. If I run this code I get a null object returned. If I change that user id to "me" or my user id it works fine as well. Can anyone please help?